# Why time_field cannot show saved data in 'edit' action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use the `time_field` in `'new' action (lectures/new.html.erb)` in the form that create a new lecture. 
`time_field` has a default time format(*:*) in my app that only allows user change the number before and after `':'`. 
However when I use `time_field` in (edit.html.erb) in the form for showing and updating, the time field is blank. 
So I need to type that time again.  The controller has no problem, all other data is shown correctly in the 'edit' form. 
How can I show the start-time in lecture.new as the default value in edit?

```
 <%=label_tag "Start Time" %><br>
 <%= f.time_field :start_time, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Example: 10:00" %>
```

By the way, placeholder info will not appear like in 'text-field'.

Comment: how looks yr actually form ?

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= form_for @lecture do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag "Start Time" %><br>
  <% if @lecture.new_record? %>
    <%= f.time_field :start_time, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Example: 10:00" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.time_field : start_time , value: "#{@lecture.start_time}" %>
  <% end %>
<%- end %>
```

i was also facing the same issue, but I have fixed using this logic/code.
i hope this will help you to show saved data in 'edit' action.

Answer (score 0):

Because you shall to pass to form not a symbol, but actual record value, so you'll get something like this:

```
<%= form_for @lecture do |f| %>
   <%= label_tag "Start Time" %><br>
   <%= f.time_field :start_time, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Example: 10:00" %>
<%- end %>
```

of course you have to ensure that `@lecture` has been set properly up for the *edit* action, in such way as:

```
 @lecture = Lecture.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Comment: @runchu make sure that you have properly setup the `@lecture` var, for edit action

Comment: @lecture var is no problem and work fine with other data like the title, location and so on.. of the lecture

Comment: @runchu so the just the sart_time field is empty?